# sql Extract all img src tags from stored html

Tags: html, sql, image, sql-server-2008, substring

Ok... this should be fairly straight forward but I cant get my head around the easiest way to do it.

I want to run a query against my database, to look at 'Description' and pull out any
    <img src="pathtoimage.jpg" /> tags so I can throw them into a separate table...

the logic to me seems that first you find the starting point of the img tag, then the closing tag and take the substring from start to finish... however, I also have <p> tags so I can simply get the index of < and take that as my start because it will pick up the p tags as well... 
so am I going to have to get index of < then take a substring of say 2 to check if it is a p or img or href or whatever, and then only take substring if it matches img, or is there a much easier way that I am just totally missing??

I guess the other bit I should have mentioned is once I have the img tags in a new table, I also want to save the description without them in it.

Comment: Have you tried using the [LIKE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) operator?

Comment: Can multiple tags appear in a single description value?

Comment: sorry, I have already used the like to eliminate rows that don't contain <img> so I am only getting the ones back that actually do have the image tags...

Comment: using Sql Server 2008, and yes there can be multiple img tags in a single description, so I want to grab each one out

Answer (score 2):

Ok... so after thinking about this all morning... I finally came up with a solution that works, so I though I would share it...

What I needed: a way to loop through my product descriptions and pull out any images that were part of the description html, eg: logos or product images etc.. and put these in their own table, with an association to the product, then remove them out of the description.  Some products had multiple images, some had a single one.

The solution:

```
declare @prodId int
declare getproduct cursor for select Id from Product where IsActive = 1 and Description like '%<img src%'
declare @imgString varchar(200)
declare @endPos int
declare @desc varchar(max)
declare @position int
declare @outputDesc varchar(max)

    open getproduct
fetch next from getproduct into @prodId

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
            -- get product Id
    select @desc = Description from Product where Id = @prodId

  --gets the index of the first instance of <img
    select @position = CHARINDEX('<img', @desc)
    while @position < len(@desc)
    begin
        --this assumes that we are not at the end of the description field
        if (SUBSTRING(@desc, @position, 4) = '<img')
        begin

                select @endPos = charIndex('>', substring(@desc, @position, 200))
                select @imgString = substring(@desc, @position, @endPos)



                    insert into dbo.ProductImage(ProductId, ImageUrl, DisplayName, IsPrimaryImage)
                    select @prodId, @imgString, DisplayName, 0 
                    from Product where Id = @prodId
                                 and not exists (select ImageUrl from ProductImage where ProductId = @prodId and ImageUrl = @imgString)


                select @outputDesc = REPLACE(@desc, @imgString, '')
                select @outputDesc = Replace(@outputDesc, '</img>', '')

                select @position = @endPos  

        end
        else
        begin
                           -- if we have reached here, there are no more instances of <img 
            -- set @position to end of description field to prevent continuous looping
            select @position = len(@desc)
        end




    end 

    select @outputDesc

    update Product 
    set Description = @outputDesc
    where Id = @prodId

    select Description from Product where Id = @prodId



fetch next from getproduct into @prodId
end

close getproduct
deallocate getproduct
```

It might not be the most glamourous way of doing it, and could probably be tidied up a bit, but it works...